# To update item in adapter inside view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I am struggling to get solution for this.
I have a a gridView inside view page one page. I need to upload image into it from gallery and load to server.
I am not getting idea to upload on gridview item

Here is clear picure.
Viewpager -> two tabes -> one tab layout with grid view of images.
second tab layout with other input fields.

Now Open layout 1 in new adapter and set images. Now how to set new gallery image in that image view. as this is on 2nd layer.
Fragment->viewpagerAdapter->gridView adapter containing images grid view.
Below code inside PagerAdapter

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   // return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    // Using different layouts in the view pager instead of images.
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = -1;

    View view = null;

 switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.activity_image_banner;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, container, false);
             recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.banneregridView);

            GridLayoutManager trend_manager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(trend_manager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            BannerDetailsAdapter bannerDetailsAdapter  = new    BannerDetailsAdapter(activity,context, vBannerPic);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(bannerDetailsAdapter);


            break;

        case 1:

        resId = R.layout.improvelisting_details_layout;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, container, false);
```

and this is recycleView Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  BannerDetailsAdapter.Business business, final int position) {

    IL_BusinessProfileBanner businessPojo  = businessDataPojoList.get(position);
    Log.e("Position is-", "--" + businessPojo.getVBannerPic());

  //  business.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo);


    Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).
            load(businessPojo.getVBannerPic())
            .into(business.image);

    business.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImproveListingFragment.loadImagefromGallery(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: plz post relevant code here

Comment: @Makarand is it clear from the explaination

Comment: Do post code and relevant screenshots to clarify the question.

Comment: post code of what you've done so far

Comment: @nik  and ravi please chck updated question

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Get the image from gallery [you are doing it right]

   ```
   business.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       ImproveListingFragment.loadImagefromGallery(position);
   }
   });
   ```
2. Create a global variable of `vBannerPic`
3. Assign the image you got from gallery to this variable
4. and then call `recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`